# swap cells in a dataframe to minimize the effect to the sum of the difference of correlation

Tags: python, r

Assume there is a dataframe below:

```
set.seed(100)
toydata <- data.frame(x = sample(1:50,50,replace = T),
                      y = sample(1:50,50,replace = T),
                      z = sample(1:50,50,replace = T)
                      )
```

Then I find all the cells whose values are below 10. For the first column:

```
toydata[toydata$x<10,1]
```

I get

```
[1] 3 9 9 7
```

For the second column,

```
toydata[toydata$y<10,2]
```

I get ,I get

```
[1] 7 5 2 7 2
```

For the third column,

```
toydata[toydata$z<10,3]
```

I get

```
[1] 3 1 5 2 2 6 1 3 5 8 7 3 1
```

and their positions

```
which(toydata$x<10)
[1]  4 10 26 40
which(toydata$y<10)
[1]  7 30 35 48 49
which(toydata$z<10)
[1]  3  9 13 16 26 30 36 38 42 43 45 48 49
```

I want to swap the values among the cells whose values are lesser than 10.The values in other cells whose values are equal to or more than 10 remain unchanged.

The condition is that each cell whose value is  lesser than 10 must be replaced by a new value.

The objective is to minimize the sum of the difference of correlation before and after being swapped, says minimize |cor(x,y)-cor(x',y')|+|cor(x,z)-cor(x',z')|+|cor(y,z)-cor(y',z')|.

x', y', z' are the new columns which has ben swapped.

|| means the absolute value.

Are there any good suggestions to fulfill this in R or Python with any packages?

Thanks.

Comment: You want to swap the values keeping the same values?

Comment: @RuiBarradas,Thanks.Yes, for example, If there are 5 values, say 1, 2, 3, 4, 4. so I have one 1, one 2, one 3, and two 4s be swapped. one possibility after swapping is 4, 4, 1, 2, 3. But 2, 1, 4, 3, 4 is not what I want, because in the fifth position, the original value and swapped value are both 4 which are unchanged.

Comment: But then there would be datasets where that would be impossible. If, say, all but one values less than `10` are equal, some would be swapped by equal values. Imagine 1, 4, 4.

Comment: Yes. Special case like this definitely exits. so if a feasible solution can not be found. we need output 'no feasible solution found'.....and then we may increase the threshold to see whether there is a feasible solution.

Answer (score 1):

If all you want to do is to swap the values below a certain threshold, meaning a permutation of those values, `sample` is your friend.

```
swapFun <- function(x, n = 10){
  inx <- which(x < n)
  x[sample(inx)] <- x[inx]
  x
}

toydata[toydata$x < 10, 1]
#[1] 3 9 9 7
which(toydata$x < 10)
#[1]  4 10 26 40

toy <- toydata    # Work with a copy
toy[] <- lapply(toydata, swapFun)

toy[toy$x < 10, 1]
#[1] 9 7 3 9
which(toy$x < 10)
#[1]  4 10 26 40
```

Note that the order of the values less than `10` has changed but not where they can be found.

If you want another threshold, say `25`, just do

```
toydata[] <- lapply(toydata, swapFun, n = 25)
```

To swap between columns, use another function. It starts by transforming the input `data.frame` into a vector. The swapping is done in the same way. Then back to `data.frame`.

```
swapFun2 <- function(DF, n = 10){
  x <- unlist(DF)
  inx <- which(x < n)
  x[sample(inx)] <- x[inx]
  x <- as.data.frame(matrix(x, ncol = ncol(DF)))
  names(x) <- names(DF)
  x
}

toy2 <- swapFun2(toydata)
```

Comment: Thanks. But, this function seems  just  can swap values in each column, I also want  to swap between  different columns.

Comment: @Orchard'sStory See the new function at the end.

Comment: Hi Rui, Thanks a lot. Do know how to deal with that special case we discussed just now that if I want every value to be replaced by a new one?

Comment: I want to stop the for loop if the difference is lesser than 0.001, but it does not work. Could you please give me any suggestions?`for (i in 1:10000) {
   toy2 <- swapFun2(toydata)
   toydata<-toy2
   if(abs(cor(toy2$x,toy2$y)-cor(toydata$x,toydata$y))+abs(cor(toy2$x,toy2$z)-cor(toydata$x,toydata$z))+abs(cor(toy2$z,toy2$y)-cor(toydata$z,toydata$y))) < 0.001
      break
    }`